# creation of new column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Hellooo

I want to create a new column (D) that includes calculations from previous columns (A,B,C).

> [image]

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just do so directly

```py
df["D"] = df["A"] + df["B"] + df["C"]
```

Comment: first row is "df["C"] + df["A"] - df["B"]" and rest of the row is "df["C"] - df["A"] + df["B"]"

Comment: You can either do a conditional based on the index of the row or remove that first row as a special case. Implementation is up to you, but that departs from your stated question. Check [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for future questions